# PHP Notifications

Tags: php, notifications

Ok so maybe I am just blanking out here but I am making a notification system and I am using PHP as my backend. I am using the following code to set up the correct number of notifications

```
$updates = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates WHERE userid = '$uid'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    if ($updates>0) {
        for ($i=0; $i<$updates;$i++) {
            echo '
                <li class="update">'.$updates.'</li>
            ';
         }
    } else {
        echo'<h4 class="nonew">No New Notifications</h4>';
    }
}
```

This code will echo the correct number of notifications but will echo the entire where it supposed to echo that single comments content. How do I echo only the contents of that single notification? I am sure this has a simple answer and I already know it but I just can't think of it right now. Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Heres my database structure:

```
Updates
-id
-userid
-active
-date
-content
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what is stored in `$updates`?

Comment: Your edit does not help. Show us the value of `$updates`

Comment: Hi Joseph, do you have an array of updates? It looks like you are using `$updates` as a number.

Comment: @JosephTorracca ...I wonder, have you queried the database for your updates yet? If so, how did you store the results?

Comment: `$updates = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates WHERE userid='$uid'");` I store them in an array

Comment: Bingo. We found your problem. :)

Comment: @josh i think you are already posting the answer so i am moving the the next question :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// In case $uid comes from user input
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($uid);

// Fetch the user's notifications
$updates = mysql_query("SELECT content FROM updates WHERE userid = '" . $uid . "'");

if (mysql_num_rows($updates))
{
    // Output the user's notifications
    while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($updates))
    {
        echo '<li class="update">' . $get['content'] . '</li>' . "\n";
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<h4 class="nonew">No New Notifications</h4>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I never thought of using `mysql_num_rows`. Thanks!

Comment: To be cautious, perhaps provide a reminder to sanitize `$uid` in case it is taken from user input.

Comment: It is not taken from user input

Comment: @Josh - Right, updated the answer with a mysql_real_escape_string() function just in case :)